# Mysql conditions with grouping many-to-many tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I was wondering if somebody can think of a more elegant solutions to my problem. I have trouble finding similar cases.

I have 5 tables. 3 are details for employees, skills and subskills. The remaining 2 are linking tables.

skill_links

```
skill_id    subskill_id
1           4
1           5
2           4
2           6
```

emp_skill_links

```
employee_id    subskill_id    acquired
1              4              2013-04-05 00:00:00
1              5              2014-02-24 00:00:00
2              6              2012-02-26 00:00:00
2              5              2011-06-14 00:00:00
```

Both have many-to-many relations. Skills with subskills (skill_links) and employees with subskills (emp_skill_links).

I want to pick employees who have acquired all subskills for a skill. I tried doing it with one query, but couldn't manage it with the grouping involved. At the moment my solution is two separate queries and matching these in php array later. That is:

```
SELECT sl.skill_id, COUNT(sl.subskill_id) as expected
FROM skill_links sl
GROUP BY sl.skill_id
```

to be compared with:

```
SELECT sl.skill_id, esl.employee_id, COUNT(esl.subskill_id) as provided
FROM emp_skill_links esl
INNER JOIN skill_links sl
ON sl.subskill_id = esl.subskill_id
GROUP BY sl.skill_id, esl.employee_id
```

Is there a more efficient single query solution to my problem? Or would it not be worth the complexity involved?

Comment: Are `employee_id` and `skill_id` somehow directly related? Otherwise it doesn't make sense as `subskill_id` are no unique.

Comment: No. With the database structure I have at the moment the only link between them is through skill_links.

Comment: Do you mean only through `subskill_id` field? Then it should work only if `subskill_id` is unique.

Comment: subskill_id is my only link on employee-subskills-skills. I'm not sure what uniqueness you mean. Each employee's subskills are unique, but many employees can have matching subskills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider a query consisting of sub-queries as meeting your requirement for "a more efficient single query solution" (depends on your definition of "single query"), then this will work.

```
SELECT employeeTable.employee_id
FROM
  (SELECT sl.skill_id, COUNT(*) AS subskill_count
  FROM skill_links sl
  GROUP BY sl.skill_id) skillTable
  JOIN
  (SELECT esl.employee_id, sl2.skill_id, COUNT(*) AS employee_subskills
   FROM emp_skill_links esl
     JOIN skill_links sl2 ON esl.subskill_id = sl2.subskill_id
   GROUP BY esl.employee_id, sl2.skill_id) employeeTable
  ON skillTable.skill_id = employeeTable.skill_id
 WHERE employeeTable.employee_subskills = skillTable.subskill_count
```

What the query does:

- Select the count of sub-skills for each skill
- Select the count of sub-skills for each employee for each main skill
- Join those results based on the main skill
- Select the employees from that who have a sub-skill count equal to
  the count of sub-skills for the main skill

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0ce9/6)

In the is example, users 1 and 3 each have all sub-skills of main skill 1. User 2 only has 2 of the 3 sub-skills of main skill 2.

You'll note that the logic here is similar to what you're already doing, but it has the advantage of just one db request (instead of two) and it doesn't involve the PHP work of creating, looping through, comparing, and reducing arrays.

Comment: This is a neat solution. Thank you.